# Check for worksheet protection

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I have written Excel parser that uses PHPExcel library to parse and compare two Excel files. It works fine and prints out the differences.

Now I want to check whether certain worksheets are password protected (read only if you don't have the password). I was experimenting with:

```
$excelObj->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()
$excelObj->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->isProtectionEnabled()
$excelObj->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->getPassword()
```

but it always returns false for every method - like the file is not protected even though the original Excel file that is parsed is protected and can't be edited in MS Excel.

How can I check if a worksheet is write-protected using only PHP?

Comment: Is it only worksheet protection or shouldn't you be checking for workbook protection as well?

Comment: even if I check workbook protection - e.g. $excelOb->getSecurity() result is always false...

Comment: You can check out this demo excel file: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22695749/phpexcel/test-protection.xls and this PHP script: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22695749/phpexcel/test.php 

This excel file has two sheets - Sheet 1 is protected and Sheet 2 not. But if you execute the test.php the output will be

Worksheet: Sheet1
Is protected: false
.....
Worksheet: Sheet2
Is protected: false

even though Sheet1 IS protected and can not be edited in Excel without unlocking

Answer (score 0):

I know that it has been a while but the answer may be helpful for someone with this kind of issue. I had exacatly the same problem (`getProtection` method always returning false even though worksheets were protected).

**Answer:**

Remove `$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);` from your code. It seems that it strips information about formatting ... including about security status.